# Add text to a cell in column X if match in column Y

Tags: excel, text, cell, addition, vba

I'm trying to do the following thing:

My file has 2 columns.

In "A" is a full list of products ordered by clients.

In "C" is a list of products which need to have a specific text added in "A" column, in case they've been ordered (it's unfortunately not possible to do it in the database).

I don't know how to end the macro:

```
Sub SEARCH2()

    Dim CompareRange As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant

    Set CompareRange = Range("A1:A500")
    Set CompareRange2 = Range("C3:C500")
    For Each x In CompareRange2
        For Each y In CompareRange
            If x = y Then x ????? 

'THERE I WANT TO SAY ADD THE TEXT "EXAMPLE" TO THE CELL

        Next y
    Next x
End Sub
```

Could someone help to end this macro?

very best regards.

Comment: Do you mean that if the value in C is found in A you want to add "Example" to the value in C, or to A, or something else?

Comment: Yes, that's the point. it worked perfectly with the formula you wrote.
I'd never thought about using Range as Vairant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a best guess, but it's not clear what you are asking. You don't need to loop through both ranges.

```
Sub SEARCH2()

Dim CompareRange As Range, CompareRange2 As Range, x As Range, y As Range, v As Variant

Set CompareRange = Range("A1:A500")
Set CompareRange2 = Range("C3:C500")

For Each x In CompareRange2
    v = Application.Match(x, CompareRange, 0)
    If IsNumeric(v) Then
        x.Value = x.Value & " EXAMPLE"
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You must declare variable x, y as range

```
Dim CompareRange As Variant, x As Range, y As Range
If x = y Then x = "EXAMPLE"
```